# rspec testing association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

I want to test that a staff member is associated with a company in my rspec controller tests.

I would like to end up with this in my `create` action of the staff controller:

```
staff.companies << current_company
```

Where `current_company` is collected from a session variable.

How do I write a test for this?

I've got these models

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
  has_many :staff, :through => :employees
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :staff
end

class Staff < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
  has_many :companies, :through => :employees
end
```

The following test is my attempt to spec the assocation and it fails when I enter in the association code:

```
    it "should belong to the current_company" do
      staff.should_receive(:companies)
      post :create
    end
```

If I enter the 'staff.companies << current_company' code in my controller I get this error when running that test:

```
 Failure/Error: post :create
 NoMethodError:
   You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
   You might have expected an instance of Array.
   The error occurred while evaluating nil.<<
```

Staff controller create method:

```
  def create
    @staff = Staff.new(params[:staff])

    if @staff.save
      @staff.companies << current_company
      redirect_to staff_index_path, :notice => "Staff created successfully!"
    else
      @company = @staff.firm || current_company
      flash[:alert] = "Staff failed to create"
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

Comment: My guess is the error (the nil object) is in your action. Can you add your create action code from your controller -- the one that this test is calling?

Comment: To get past the nil object problem and continue on with TDD I'm using the following:  staff.should_receive(:companies).and_return([])

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would use a different approach, since testing that the model should receive a certain message couples your tests too tightly to the implementation. Do you really care whether companies receives `#<<` or some other method?

Really, what you want to test is whether the user's company is recorded when they post to the page. It doesn't matter *how* it was recorded. So I'd do something like this:

```
it "should add the company to the user's list of companies" do
  lambda do 
    post :create
  end.should change(staff.companies, :count).from(0).to(1)
  staff.companies.map(&:name).should include("Acme, Inc.")
end
```

This is testing behavior instead of implementation. The advantage is that your test wont fail when someone changes that `<<` to the equivalent `push`. It also has the advantage of being clearer about your intention and therefore better documenting the code.

Comment: Thanks Ian, that's exactly what I was looking for. That gives me a lot of room to refactor my code as well.

Comment: Great answer. Just in case you're wondering where the `nil.<<` came from: In RSpec, `staff.should_receive(:companies)` means ``staff.should_receive(:companies).and_return(nil)`

Answer (score 2):

If you're in your controller spec, I would use `stub_chain`

```
staff.stub_chain(:company, :<<).once.and_return(true)
```

which will mock out the company call AND the << call AND expect it to be called once.

(At least, that `.once` *should* work with stub_chain...)

Comment: Doesn't this just stub out the 'staff.companies << current_company'? If I use this stub and I don't include 'staff.companies << current_company' in my create method my test will still pass. I would like to make sure that the line 'staff.companies << current_company' is in my create code.

Comment: the .once. checks to make sure the chain gets called, and will raise an assertion if not. So you should be fine, I think (unless I'm missing something...)

Comment: It doesn't seem to complain if I don't have the 'staff.companies << current_company' line in my create method.

Comment: I still don't understand what `staff` in your test (everyone's tests) is referring to. Do you mean `@staff`? Or is there some setup that's not shown that defines `staff`? Or am I missing something obvious??

Comment: staff in my tests would just be a mock using 'let(:staff) {mock_model(Staff)}'

Answer (score 1):

You can test it with :

```
staff.should have(1).company
```

Or if the staff already has other companies, get the count and test for have(count+1).companies.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the code is that once you stub out a method - it no longer exists on the model anymore.

You have stubbed out the "companies" method (when you set the expectation on it) and it now, no-longer calls the actual, real companies association on the model but the stub that you have created... which returns nil (because you didn't set a returns value on it).

Then, when you try to put a company into this new, null method using << it says it can't do that.

To get around it you can do what you did which is to set a returns value:

```
staff.should_receive(:companies).and_return([])
```

which will then make sure that:

```
@staff.companies << current_company
```

will not fail with the horrible nil error (because there's and actual, real array for the company to go into).

But really the best thing to do is as the previous people have suggested and test what you actually really need to test - which is that saving a staff with companies will cause a new company to get saved to the db.